# Implementing Facebook's News Feed UITableView scroll action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

How can I implement something like Facebook's News feed header?

When a UITableView is scrolled down, a view above the UITableView disappears with the scrolling, however when scrolling up (and not at the top) the view pops back down so that the user can select "New Status", "Post a photo" and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it (and this isn't necessarily the best  way) is to use the functions which are called in the UIScrollViewDelegate. UiTableViewDelegate implements these functions. Make your View Controller the table view's delegate and then using those scrolling fictions documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html
Find out how much the user scrolled by and whether they are scrolling at the top and adjust your upper uiview's frame accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the answer in this question: [How to embed a UITableView in a UIScrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508524/how-to-embed-a-uitableview-in-a-uiscrollview)

TLDR: Use the setTableHeaderView method for your UITableView (this will scroll) with a section header (this will stick) as the popdown.