# scrolling tableview upwards and keeping tableview in complete scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

In this I need scroll complete tableview to upward and tableview should stay upwards until user again scrolls down. It should come back to its original position.

Update

I need to  scroll the tableview  top and bottom on a image

Comment: This thing happens by default. Please make sure height of table view is not more than that of screen , that might cause such issue.

Comment: Do you want to add tableView inside scrollView?

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. Show some effort and some code.

Comment: @zala yes,i need to add tableview inside scrollview,first tableview will be half of the scrollview,when we scroll complete tableview to upward tableview should stay up until the user scrolls down.actually it is scrolling upward but not staying up

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation it's not advisable to add tableView inside scrollview[(Reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html).

Now according to design of your screen either you can have one tableView and in header of that tableView you can add all static content.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508524/how-to-embed-a-uitableview-in-a-uiscrollview)

or if your design must have tableView inside scrollView then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334478/uitableview-within-uiscrollview-using-autolayout) SO question maybe helpful to you.

I'd prefer first choice if possible.

By the way if you can fix the height of tableView then you can implement tableView inside scrollView easily.