# Swift: Setting height of UIView container to the height of embedded UITableView using prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, segue

I have a `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UIView` container, which is at the bottom of a `UIScrollView` in a `UIViewController`. Here is a screenshot of the current configuration in the storyboard.

[image: screenshot]

The `UITableView` will contain responses to the selected post. Because the height and number of responses in the `UITableView` will be variable, I want the `UIView` container's height to change based on the height of the table. The current (undesirable) behavior is the `UIView` container stays a constant height, and scrolls when the `UITableView` height is greater than the `UIView` containter's height.

The most viable method seems to be having the `UITableViewController` pass the height of the table to the `UIViewController` using `prepareForSegue`, and then set the `UIView`'s height to that passed value. However, I can't seem to set a value with the height of the table until after prepareForSegue is run.

**What Isn't Working**

1. Set the identifier of the embed segue between the `UIView` and the `UITableViewController` to "embedSegue"
2. At the top of the the embedded `UITableViewController` class, create a variable to hold the height of the table:

   ```
   var tableHeight: CGFloat!
   ```
3. Still in the embedded `UITableViewController`, override `viewDidLoad` like so, printing passedHeight to the console for checking:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
       self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

       self.tableHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height
       print(tableHeight)
   }
   ```
4. In the `UIViewController` class that contains the `UIView` container, create a variable to hold the value passed from the `UITableViewController`:

   ```
   var viewHeight: CGFloat!
   ```
5. Still in the `UIViewController`, override `prepareForSegue` like so, setting viewHeight to the passed tableHeight value, and printing viewHeight to the console for checking:

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       if segue.identifier == "embedSegue" {
           let responseTableView = segue.destinationViewController as! ResponseViewController

           self.viewHeight = responseTableView.tableHeight

           if viewHeight == nil {
               print("Nil")
           } else {
               print(viewHeight)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. When I run the app, viewHeight prints as Nil first, then tableHeight prints, which means `prepareForSegue` has run prior to tableHeight being set.

I have also tried other methods besides `prepareForSegue`, including calling various functions on the `UIView` container in viewDidLayoutSubviews() like:

- .sizeThatFits()
- .needsUpdateConstraints()
- .layoutIfNeeded()

However, the `UIView` container remains the same height as set in the storyboard.

As an epilogue, this is my first StackOverflow post, and I'm excited to be joining the community. Please do let me know if I can clarify my question. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView` containing three `UIViews`, I created one `UITableView` with three custom cells. Each cell has their own custom `UITableViewCell` class for flexibility.

This meant I lost the ability to use constraints to dynamically change the height of each section. I wanted the Post Title and Post Text to be centered on a fullscreen image. To achieve this, I added the logic below:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            //Fullscreen image cell - the "20" is for the status bar
            return tableView.frame.size.height - self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20
        } else {
            //Just use the current rowHeight
            return self.tableView.rowHeight
        }
    }
```

### References

[How to embed a UITableView in a UIScrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508524/how-to-embed-a-uitableview-in-a-uiscrollview)

A short answer to a similar question which sparked the idea

[UITableview with more than One Custom Cells with Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift)

Detailed explanation of how to create a `UITableView` with 3 custom `UITableViewCells`